# Drive is disconnected but still appears as a shared drive

Tags: linux, network-shares, samba

I have a USB drive shared from a Raspberry Pi via Samba.

Everything works fine, but when I disconnect the USB drive, the mounting folder (`/media/usb1`) still exists and its still being shared through Samba as an empty folder.

What I would have expected is Samba to stop sharing that resource, and appear as disconnected or unavailable in Windows, as its mapped as a network drive.

Is there a way to tell Samba to stop sharing the resource if it's empty?
Is there any other workaround?

My `smb.conf` entry for this shared resource is the following:

```
[usbdrive]
path = /media/usb1
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
only guest = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
public = no
```

Comment: Did you unmount the USB before disconnecting?

Comment: I would suggest sharing a sub-folder on the USB media so that when you `umount`, it no longer exists.  How is samba supposed to know that it was for a removable device?  The folder is still there and still accessible.  Unix's stupidity is also it's strength.  Most things aren't overthought or over programmed.  It the organization of things by the user that make it powerful.

Comment: @harrymc No I did not unmount the USB, but I have rebooted the machine and it's still showing.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas correct, it's doing what's logical, but not what I want :) The subfolder workaround sounds like a great idea to me. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest sharing a sub-folder on the USB media so that when you `umount`, it no longer exists.

To be honest, I myself have been in your exact shoes.

Samba doesn't know that it was for a removable device as the folder is still there and still accessible.

Unix's stupidity is also it's strength. Most things aren't overthought or over programmed. It is the organization of things by the user that make it powerful.

Comment: Oh.. one other thing.  If you "pull the plug" on stuff samba is working with.  Sometimes bad things can happen.  This is far worse when using a samba-client against a windows server but bad stuff can happen the other way around too.

Comment: Yeah, I literally pulled the plug, then when I saw it still appeared in Samba I tried to unmount it and said it couldn't because it was busy... oops... I have not plugged it since, wish me good luck and not have the stupidity to do it again :)

Comment: If it works.  Please mark me as the answer you want.  If it doesn't, down-vote me and comment (please).  Good Luck! :)

Comment: Sure, I already upvoted it, I am just waiting to see if any other answers pops in, if it doesn't I will accept you answer. Thanks!